# Access the Default Keyboard Device

Tags: c, linux, file-io, device

I have a quick little C program that checks to see if a key is being held down.  Right now it works like a charm but accesses the keyboard device through `/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd`.  I know that `/dev/input/by-path/*-kbd` will hold the keyborads but I don't know how to open a file with that name.

The idea is I want it to be portable.  So if the program is run on another computer it still works.  I am not to concerned with getting multiple keyboards (does anyone use a setup like this?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You could use /proc, namely **/proc/bus/input/devices** info for getting available keyboard device list. This is the list of devices having "keyboard" in their names taken from my notebook (I've USB keyboard attached and so the answer to Your 2-nd question is "yes"):

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab54
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=4 2000000 3803078 f800d001 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04d9 Product=1603 Version=0110
N: Name="  USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event5 
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 7 ff800000 7ff febeffdf f3cfffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04d9 Product=1603 Version=0110
N: Name="  USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: EV=13
B: KEY=2000000 39fa d941d001 1e0000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0004
N: Name="ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event14 rfkill 
B: EV=3
B: KEY=ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff fffffffe
```

Comment: This is very interesting.  I could possible parse the filename.  Unfortunately the file name is in `/device` I have never heard of this before but I might be able to find out by reading a bit about proc.

Comment: That path is relative to the `sysfs` root, i.e. `/sys/`.

Comment: thx i used this when checking for my default keyboard, this should be awnser